# Timer for DOM-intensive main thread using a web worker

Tags: javascript, web-worker

In my parent page, I'm creating and adding many SVG elements to an SVG, and many DIVs to the DOM. It takes several seconds and blocks (freezes) everything until all is created and appears. I want to use a timer so the user can see something is going on (rather than a spinner) and total time taken is of interest.

A timer on the main thread locks up because everything locks up, and only shows the total time once everything has been created.

So I made use of a web worker and put the timer there. Trouble is, it wasn't able to post back to the main page and write to the receiving span during the element creation process since it was frozen.

Then I tried to put the SVG element and DIV creation routine in the web worker and the timer in the main thread. Problem is, the timer freezes up wile the blob of SVG elements and DIVs is posted from the web worker and is drawn to the parent page.

Is there another way to go about this?

Comment: Would a datastream-based approach work instead of passing a big chunk of data?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I ended up separating out some of the loops and writing timestamps from there. Not exactly what I wanted, but close enough.